# Differentiating between browser tabs and browser windows in C#

Tags: c#, assert, coded-ui-tests

This seems to be a bit of a tricky problem I am having. But do you know of a way to differentiate a browser window from a browser tab for the purposes of a CodedUI test. How would I implement this?

Comment: Most browsers treat each tab as their own instance.  This basically means a window and a tab are appear to be the samething.  What browser are you using?

Comment: IE 9. This is what I was afraid of. I am trying to meet the requirements for an automated test and I haven't been able to figure out a way to do it.

Comment: If content of a page can be recognized by an ID could fulfill your expectation?

Comment: No because that would just verify that it opened when I need to verify that it opened within a browser tab.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal, if I understand correctly, is to identify if a page you've loaded/launched is tabbed or if it launched in a new browser window.
It's agreed that a tabbed browser window is indistinguishable from a standalone browser window.
I’ve got a solution for you – admittedly it’s not terribly elegant but it should do the trick.

**Imporant:** You can switch between tabbed windows using Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab.

1. Launch the page in question
2. Start your coded-ui recording
3. If your page is tabbed, press Ctrl+Shift+Tab and this will take you to the parent page, or whichever other page you’re tabbed with.
4. Create an assertion to verify that you’re on that page.
5. Press Ctrl+Tab, and now you should be back on the new page you're testing.
6. Create an assertion to verify that you’re on that new page.
7. If these assertions pass, you know you’ve got a tabbed page; if your page loaded in a standalone browser, Ctrl+Tab/Ctrl+Shift+Tab won’t do a thing and your assertions will fail.

It'll look something like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod1()
    {
        //This takes you to the parent tab
        this.UIMap.CtrlShiftTab();
        //Assertion to confirm you're on the parent page
        this.UIMap.AssertParentPage();

        //This takes you to the new tab
        this.UIMap.CtrlTab();
        //Assertion to confirm you're on the new page
        this.UIMap.AssertNewPage();
    }
```

It should do the trick. Good luck and let us know if you found another way to get your result!

EDIT: You can also switch between tabs using Ctrl+Number. So Ctrl+1 takes you to the first tab, Ctrl+2 the second tab, and so on.